# Facebook Graph API v2.11+ - '/business_id/pages' does not return associated pages under the business manager

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am the admin of a business manager and the business id has two pages associated with it. I am the owner of one of the page and another business admin is the owner of the other page.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/business_id/pages
```

Running above snippet on graph-api explorer returns

```
{
  "error": {
  "message": "(#12) pages field is deprecated for versions v2.11 and higher",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 12,
  "fbtrace_id": "DbR8kp2GtWz"
 }
}
```

I am able to get pages related to my account straightforward via

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/accounts
```

But how can I get all pages associated to my business account instead of my personal account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11 you should now be using:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/{business_id}/owned_pages

or

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/{business_id}/client_pages

depending on your need

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the owned_pages  was the required edge for me